# Proving a modified Ackermann function using induction

Tags: induction, exponential-function, exponentiation, power-towers, ackermann-function

So I have 2 functions:

$$
a(0,y) = y+ 1\\
a(x, 0) = a(x-1,1)\\
a(x,y) = a(x-1,a(x,y-1))
$$ 
And:
$$
c(0,n) = 0\\
c(1,n) = n^2 + n +1\\
c(m,0) = c(m-1,1)\\
c(m,n) = c(m-1,c(m,n-1))
$$

And then I have: $d(n) = 2^{2^{.^{.^{.^{.^{2}}}}}}$
while the height of the power tower is $n+2$.

I need to show that $c(n,n)>d(n)$ for $n \geq 3$.

I already proved that $a(n,n)>d(n)$ for $n \geq 4$ using induction.
So if I was to prove that $c(n,n) > a(n,n)$ for $n>1$, it would mean $c(n,n) > d(n)$ for $n \geq 4$.

But what about $n=3$? Here $a(3,3)<d(3)$ but clearly $c(3,3)>d(3)$. My way to go here would be proving that $c(n,n) > a(n+1,n+1)$ for $n \geq 3$ using induction, so my end goal would be $c(n,n)>a(n+1,n+1)>d(n+1)>d(n) \Rightarrow c(n,n)>d(n)$.

**Begin:** $c(2,2) = 183 > 61 = a(3,3)$

**Assumption:** $c(n,n) > a(n+1,n+1)$ for random but fixed $n \geq 3$.

**Step:**
$$
c(n+1,n+1) = c(n,c(n+1,n)) \stackrel{Assumption, wrong?} \geq c(n,a(n+2,n+1)) \stackrel{Assumption, wrong?} > a(n+1, a(n+2,n+1) + 1) \geq a(n+1,a(n+2,n+1)) = a(n+2,n+2)
$$

I'm not sure I can use the assumption the way I'm using it to prove the induction step. I think the right way to write it would be:

**Step:**
$$
c(n+1,n+1) = c(n,c(n+1,n)) \geq c(n,c(n,n)) \stackrel{Assumption} \geq c(n,a(n+1,n+1)) ...?\\
$$

To conclude:

I'm a bit lost on how I can show that $c(n,n)>d(n)$ for $n \geq 3$, using $c(n,n) > a(n+1,n+1)$ or attentively to show that $c(n,n)>d(n)$ for $n \geq 4$, using $c(n,n) > a(n,n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$$c(1,n)>n^2$$

$$c(2,0)=3$$

Prove by induction that:

$$c(2,n)>2^{2^n}$$

And hence notice that

$$c(3,0)=c(2,1)>2^2=d(2)$$

By induction again:

$$c(3,n)>d(2n+2)$$

Which is more than sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but this will show it specifically for $c(3,n)$, I need it to work on $c(n,n)$, or is it a different side of the same coin? because $c(n,n) > c(3,n)$ for $n\geq3$?

Comment: Yes, you can show it is increasing in all arguments by induction using the same approach as showing it for the Ackermann function.